# React Query cannot send PUT request with path params using axios

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to update a product at route `/admin/products/:productId` with the following Tanstack Query `useMutation` custom hook:

```js
export function useUpdateProductByIdMutation() {

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['updateProductById'], // error???
    mutationFn: (productId: string, newProduct: any) => {
      return axiosPrivate.put(`/admin/products/${productId}`, { data: { newProduct } });
    },
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getAllProducts']);
    },

  });
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ mutationKey: string[]; mutationFn: (productId: string, newProduct: any) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>; onSettled: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mutationKey' does not exist in type 'readonly unknown[]'.
```

Why can't we use path params with Tanstack Query `useMutation`?

I'm all ears for any enlightenment on this!

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED! It seems React Query's `mutationFn` only accepts 1 parameter

```js
interface IUpdateProductParams {
  productId: string;
  newProduct: any;
}

export function useUpdateProductByIdMutation() {

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['updateProductById'],
    mutationFn: (args: IUpdateProductParams) => { // mutation function only accepts 1 parameter
      const { productId, newProduct } = args;
      return axiosPrivate.put(`/admin/products/${productId}`, { newProduct });
    },
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getAllProducts']);
    },

  });
}
```